# Error "HttpServletRequest refers to the missing type String"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2

I am implementing a project in struts in which I am getting an error in a JSP page.

I have already configured Tomcat 6, the JRE and JDK 6 in Eclipce IDE.

The code is:

```
%request.getContextPath()%
```

The error is:

```
The method getContextPath() from the type HttpServletRequest refers to the missing type String
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You haven't added the JRE libraries to your IDE. Add it.

Answer (score 8):

click on your project and go to build path configure updated jre path and Select the library type to add